# Theorem 18 in *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

In the proof of this theorem on page 97, it is said:

> i.e., $B$ is a normal subgroup of the subgroup $AB$.

But I don't understand how this follows from the fact that $AB \leq N_G(B)$. Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: $B$ is normal in $N_G(B)$, then if $B\leq AB \leq N_G(B)$, we must have $B$ is normal in $AB$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $B=eB\subset AB$ we have $B\leq AB$.

If $g\in AB\leq N_G(B)$, then $g\in N_G(B)$, so $gBg^{-1}=B$.

Thus $B$ is normal in $AB$.

In general, if $B\leq C\leq N_G(B)$, then $B$ is normal in $C$.

Comment: I guess this also means that $AB$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G(B)$, and any subgroup of $N_G(B)$ is normal.

Comment: It's also written there that "Since $B$ is normal in $AB$, the quotient group $AB/B$ is well defined." I'm not seeing why.

Comment: @sequence How do you figure? If $g\in N_G(B)$, then $gABg^{-1}=gAg^{-1}gBg^{_1}=(gAg^{-1})B$, but we do not know that $(gAg^{-1})B=AB$ unless we happen to know $gAg^{-1}=A$, which we don't know unless we happen to know $N_G(B)\subset N_G(A)$.

Comment: @sequence Whenever $H$ is normal in $G$, the set of (left)-cosets $G/H$ has a well-defined group operation. You may wish to review the chapter in your textbook defining quotient groups.

Comment: Can we take $gA(g^{-1}g)Bg^{-1} = gA1Bg^{-1}=gABg^{-1}$?

Comment: @sequence Yes, $gA(g^{-1} g)Bg^{-1}$ is, by definition, the set of all elements of the form $gag^{-1}gbg^{-1}$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. This is equal to $gabg^{-1}$, which is precisely the elements of $gABg^{-1}$.

Comment: OK I got it. Of course  $gABg^{-1}$ is not necessarily equal to $AB$.

Answer (score 1):

It is better if we try to express everything in words. I will read "$AB\leq N_G(B)$" as "$AB$ normalizes $B$" which exactly means "$B$ is normal in $AB$" (since $B$ is *subgroup* of $AB$).

On the other hand, in Klein-4 group $\{e,a,b,c\}$, the subgroup $\{e,a\}$ normalizes subgroup $\{e,b\}$ but we can not say $\{e,a\}$ is normal *in* $\{e,b\}$ because of no subgroup relation between them.